# Schema-validation: missing table

Tags: java, liquibase

I wanted to create  table in the database using liquibase but he don't appear and I get an error about missing table. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

In application.yml I have spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

create-activities-table.xml:

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <changeSet author="Damian Malicki" id="create-activities-table.xml">
        <createTable tableName="activity">
            <column name="id" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="description" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="created_by_id" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="type" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="created_on" type="datetime">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

database changelog:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      file: classpath:db/changelog/activities/create-activities-table.xml
```

ActivityEntity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "activity")
public class ActivityEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "created_by_id")
    private String createdById;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private ActivityType type;
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
//    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "activitiesId")
//    private List<ActivityParamEntity> activityParamEntityList;


}
```

I've already tried to rewrite the code, rewrite it and nothing change.

When I try liquibase update it appeared:

```
#################################################### 
##   _     _             _ _                      ## 
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ## 
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ## 
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ## 
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ## 
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ## 
##              | |                               ## 
##              |_|                               ## 
##                                                ## 
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ## 
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ##
##  Free schema change activity reports at        ##
##      https://hub.liquibase.com                 ##
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starting Liquibase at 19:19:11 (version 4.19.0 #6648 built at 2023-01-17 15:02+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.19.0
Liquibase Open Source 4.19.0 by Liquibase
Error parsing command line: Invalid argument '--changelog-file': missing required argument. If you need to configure new liquibase project files and arguments, run the 'liquibase init 
project' command.

For detailed help, try 'liquibase --help' or 'liquibase <command-name> --help'
```

Comment: Have you tried running `liquibase update` to run the changeset ?

Comment: I just tried it and posted the result

Comment: Yeah the error you posted tells that liquibase is not installed in your system. Follow this link to see the installation process https://docs.liquibase.com/start/install/liquibase-windows.html. Another possiblity is that liquibase is installed on your system but the binary path is not added to your path environment variable

Comment: I install liquibase and change result

Comment: Yeah you need to precise path to the changelog file using the --changelog-file param. Specially given that the project wasn't initialized. So you would run something like `liquibase update --changelog-file /path/to/your/changelog/file`

Comment: when i use this command this error appears:
Invalid argument '--url':

Comment: Yes i just seen the docs, and so liquibase update need more than the --changelog-file, it also need the `--url , --username, --password` arguments. So your full command would look like this `liquibase update --changelog-file /path --url connectionString --username YOUR_DB_USER_NAME --password YOUR_DB_USER_PASSWORD`. But instead of precising all thoses arguments in the terminal, you can also use a configuration file. Here is a link that explains how to setup a configuration file https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/connections/creating-config-properties.html

Comment: thanks for all your help, I'll check it out tomorrow as i have to go to work now

Comment: When I wanted to use this command I noticed that I had a small typo in the folder. And now everything works, thank you very much